# Getting Error While Decryption An AES Encrypted String In Cpp

Tags: python, c++, cryptography, runtime-error, aes

When I decrypt a string with the decryption function I got some redundant characters. Actually, this code is written for encrypting and decrypting raw bytes.

**Here is my code.**

**Python AES Encryption Script:**

```
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import hashlib

def encrypt_string(plaintext, key):
    iv = 16 * b'\x00'
    cipher = AES.new(hashlib.sha256(key).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext.encode(), AES.block_size))
    return ciphertext

KEY = get_random_bytes(16)

try:
    plaintext = input(">> ")
except:
    print("Input string needed!")
    sys.exit()

ciphertext = encrypt_string(plaintext, KEY)

print('AESkey[] = { 0x' + ', 0x'.join(hex(x)[2:] for x in KEY) + ' };')
print('payload[] = { ' + ', '.join(str(x) for x in ciphertext) + ' };')
```

---

**CPP Decryption Function:**

```
int AESDecrypt(char * payload, unsigned int payload_len, char * key, size_t keylen) {
        HCRYPTPROV hProv;
        HCRYPTHASH hHash;
        HCRYPTKEY hKey;

        if (!CryptAcquireContextW(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)){
                return -1;
        }
        if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash)){
                return -1;
        }
        if (!CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)key, (DWORD)keylen, 0)){
                return -1;              
        }
        if (!CryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, 0,&hKey)){
                return -1;
        }
        
        if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, (HCRYPTHASH) NULL, 0, 0, payload, &payload_len)){
                return -1;
        }
  
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding won't be stripped off in the call to `CryptDecrypt()` because you haven't set the third parameter to `TRUE`. Thus your call *should* be

```cpp
if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, (HCRYPTHASH) NULL, TRUE, 0, payload, &payload_len)){
        return -1;
}
```

or, if you insist on avoiding informative constants,

```cpp
if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, (HCRYPTHASH) NULL, 1, 0, payload, &payload_len)){
        return -1;
}
```

As an aside, I noticed in the [Microsoft documentation for CryptDecrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecrypt) that the Remarks section describing the function of the third parameter contains a critical mistake. It says that when the third parameter is `TRUE`:

> If the key is a block cipher key, **the data is padded to a multiple of**
> **the block size of the cipher.** To find the block size of a cipher, use
> CryptGetKeyParam to get the KP_BLOCKLEN value of the key.

That's actually what happens on **encrypt**, not decrypt. Microsoft just copy & pasted the documentation for `CryptEncrypt` and failed to change that part of it. What actually happens is that, if the third parameter is `TRUE`, the padding is *removed*,